# Apply same formula to large column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have 928 numbers in one column in excel. I need to apply the same conversion formula to all these numbers. I've been looking around here and most of the answers to similar questions tell me to use `ctrl` + `down` or click and drag the little corner of the formula cell.

I tried these suggestions but `ctrl` + `down` highlights the entire column all the way down to row 1048576, I just need down to 928. I'd rather not have to populate the entire column and then delete all the 0s from 929-1048576. The second option I was already aware of but I'd rather not click and drag for 928 rows. The next sets of numbers I have to do are even larger.

Here is the gist of how I have my sheet set up:

```
Numbers    Conversion
190         =A2*3.28
250
430
032
etc
```

In Excel the formula shows up as a number of course. If I did only have four numbers to convert, clicking and dragging or even manually filling in the formula would be no big deal. Is there a way I can direct the formula to populate for specifically 928 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column with the formula is adjacent to the data, you can double click the fill handle (i.e., the black square in the lower right-hand corner of the cell). This will automatically fill the formula down to the last cell adjacent to data in the column to the left.

Comment: My formula column was not adjacent to the data, but that's easily remedied. I'm curious if there's a method for situations where formula and data columns aren't next to each other... Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Clueless Use ctrl+down to move to the last cell of your data column, then use the arrow keys to navigate to the column where you have your formula. Press ctrl+shift+up to highlight the entire column, then ctrl+D to autofill.

Comment: @Kyle thank you! this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty but you could use a dummy column to count the row numbers (so start at 1, 2, and then use the copy page down to fill the entire column with the corresponding row numbers), and then use ctrl+f to find 928 in the list. Then put some character in the conversion column row 928. Now you can use the page down trick in the conversion column and it will stop at row 928.